# find total of positive and negative numbers separately inline, using only select and case statement

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a question. If I am given a table with positive and negative numbers and I want to find total of all positives and total of all negatives separately and display it in one line. I was able to come up with one solution (below). I wanted to check if it is possible to have a better solution using Select and CASE statement

```
id  amount
1   100
2   -10
3   50
4   -80
5   20
6   -20

positive negative
170         -110
```

My Solution:

```
    create table #temp (id int, amount int)
insert into #temp values (1, 100)
insert into #temp values (2, -10)
insert into #temp values (3, 50)
insert into #temp values (4, -80)
insert into #temp values (5, 20)
insert into #temp values (6, -20)

with positive as 
(select sum(amount) as posNum from temp where amount > 0)
, negative as 
(select sum(amount) as negNum from temp where amount < 0)
select *, (select * from negative) from positive
```

Comment: [tag:mysql] and [tag:sql-server] are two completely different products. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Use conditional aggregation: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e2fa9cc6aee27cc501c9cda98bc2cf2d

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN amount > 0 THEN amount END) AS positive,
    SUM(CASE WHEN amount < 0 THEN amount END) AS negative
FROM #temp;
```

Output:

```
positive    negetive
170         -110
```

Comment: Need to wait 10 min, before I can do it.

Comment: I was asked this in an interview and the interviewer was hell bent on this kind of answer, and I cannot think of something so simple. Thanks for your help man

Comment: Getting greedy, can you answer this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52548531/find-without-using-lead-lag-and-cte-missing-value-from-a-list

Comment: @kushalbhola, I've answered it - you can check there

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `sign()` to determine it is positive or negative number

```
select  sum(case when sign(amount) = 1 then amount end),
        sum(case when sign(amount) = -1 then amount end)
from    #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

**This will work:**

1) For SQL Server

```
SELECT
    SUM(IIF(amount > 0, amount, 0)) positive,
    SUM(IIF(amount < 0, amount, 0)) negative
FROM TABLENAME;
```

2) For SQL Server and MySQL

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN amount > 0 THEN amount END) positive,
    SUM(CASE WHEN amount < 0 THEN amount END) negative
FROM TABLENAME;
```