# Find without using lead lag and CTE missing value from a list

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I am given a table like below. Now based on this we know that there is only 1 ID i.e. 4 which is missing. Is there a way to find this without
using Lead, Lag, CTE and only using single select and Joins

```
ID  Name
1   Tom
2   Betty
3   Ram
5   John
6   Doe
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a self join and check if the "previous" value is missing:

```
SELECT t1.ID - 1 AS Missing_ID
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table1 t2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID - 1
WHERE t2.ID IS NULL AND t1.ID > 1
```

Output:

```
Missing_ID
4
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d69e53/3)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to detect a single missing gap, then consider the following query:

```
SELECT ID - 1 AS missing
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID - 1) AND ID > 1;
```

The logic here is to check, for each record, that an `ID` value which is one less than the current row being scanned does *not* exist.  In this case, we return the current `ID` value minus one.

### Demo

But a perhaps better approach would be to left join a table containing the full possible sequence to your current table, and then asserting the missing values:

```
WITH numbers AS (
    SELECT 1 AS Number 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Number + 1
    FROM Numbers
    WHERE Number + 1 <= 6     -- replace with greatest number in your sequence
) 

SELECT n.Number
FROM numbers n
LEFT JOIN yourTable t
    ON n.Number = t.ID
WHERE t.ID IS NULL
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 255);
```

Comment: I tried your solution, it gives wrong ans. Can you also explain your approach a little bit

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in there.  It works now, but I am also adding another approach.

Comment: Its working now, thank you. Can maybe write a small explanation of your solution

Comment: I like the recursive CTE for a numbers table. Does `(MAXRECURSION 255)` mean that it won't generate a value greater than 256?

Comment: @Nick Yes, but that number can be increased, reasonably speaking at least.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with the `ROW_NUMBER()` function:

```
SELECT tempid
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS tempid
    FROM #temp
) a
LEFT JOIN #temp
    ON a.tempid = #temp.id
WHERE #temp.id IS NULL;

tempid
4
```

### Demo